# PC won't boot from upgraded HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, clone, macrium

I'm attempting to upgrade my Windows 10 PC hard drive from 1.5tb to 4tb. I currently have both drives installed and have used Macrium Reflect to clone the smaller drive onto the larger one. 1.5tb drive is MBR, new one is GPT.

The PC won't boot from the new drive and I'm not sure whether I set up the clone properly. I tried booting with just the new drive connected and got this message;

"Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

With both drives connected but swapped positions (i.e. new drive plugged into the old drives SATA port) the PC just shut down almost immediately.

This is how the resulting hard drive set up looked in disk management afterwards; you can see there's no mention of "Boot" on the cloned drive in the main partition.

[image: Hard drive setup]

I'm going to try again but am wondering if I need to do something different this time? Do I need to clone all three partitions or just the main (C) one? What are the other two for?
Is there a specific option I have to select to ensure the new drive can be booted from afterwards?

Thanks for any help.

Paul

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to boot?  Error messages, list them in your question.  Is your old hard drive MBR or GPT, because the new one is >2tb it has to be GPT.

Comment: Apologies, just realised I didn't answer your question. Old drive is MBR.